# Do Naruto and Sasuke lose their powers after the final battle?

Tags: naruto

In chapter 698, Naruto and Sasuke have lost their hands which had the symbols given by the sage of six paths.

**Does it mean that they lost the six paths power?

Does Sasuke lose his rinnegan?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Naruto and the Sage of Six Paths volume 70 chapter 670: He of the Beginning, Naruto and Sasuke meet Ōtsutsuki Hagoromo, aka Sage of Six Paths, in that chapter Hagoromo tells Naruto and Sasuke about his sons Indra and Ashura, his mother Kaguya, Ten Tails, the ninja creed, the chakra fruit, and a couple of other stuff. Then in chapter 671: Naruto and the Sage of Six Paths, Hagoromo talks more about his mother, the tailed beast, the Uchiha Stone Table, the reincarnates, and then after he finishes talking he tells them both to raise their dominant arm. Once they did, he shared his powers with them.

In chapter 690: Ninja History page 194, after Naruto and Sasuke sealed Kaguya away, it shows Naruto and Sasuke's hands without the sun and the moon. Then on the other page, 195, it shows Hagoromo looking at his hands and it shows that he got the sun and the moon back (on his hands). Then he said "They've done it. All that's left is to bring you back!!" (depends on the translation version you got) then he clapped his hands.

So that means Naruto and Sasuke lost Six Paths power before they lost their arms.

To answer the other question. No, Sasuke does not lose his Rinnegan. In Naruto The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring: Uchiha Sarada in chapter 700+6: Without Evolution page 113, it shows Sasuke using Rinnegan. He uses the Rinnegan in other occasions in the same book.

Side note: I think in Naruto The Last Movie Sasuke has the Rinnegan, but I'm not sure if he uses it. And also if you awaken Rinnegan it is yours permanently, so there way no way Sasuke could have lost his Rinnegan. I mean it's like if you awaken the Sharingan.... it won't go away.

Sources:

- Naruto volume 70: Naruto and the Sage of Six Paths
- Naruto The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring: Uchiha Sarada

Comment: Sasuke has rinnegan with tomoe , and naruto still have sealed hatred mode.

Answer (score 1):

Naruto does have his Six Path powers, it shows it in *The Last: Naruto The Movie* when he was fighting Toneri on the moon. Naruto unleashes Kurama and uses the Sage of the Six Path mode with him.

It also shows it in *Boruto: Naruto the Movie* when Naruto and Sasuke fight Momoshiki. Again, Naruto unleashes Kurama, but this time, Sasuke gives Kurama armor and a katana. Therefore Naruto at least has his Sixth Path powers, not as sure about Sasuke though.